# Grouping data based on time interval in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to group and aggregate data. I have grouped it based on date and other fields since its very straight forward. now I am also trying to group it based on time intervals[Server_Time]

```
EventID AccessReason    Source  Server_Date Server_Time
847495004   Granted ORSB_GND_GYM_IN 10/1/2016   7:25:52 AM
847506432   Granted ORSB_GND_GYM_IN 10/1/2016   8:53:38 AM
847512725   Granted ORSB_GND_GYM_IN 10/1/2016   10:18:50 AM
847512768   Granted ORSB_GND_GYM_IN 10/1/2016   10:19:32 AM
847513357   Granted ORSB_GND_GYM_OUT 10/1/2016  10:25:36 AM
847513614   Granted ORSB_GND_GYM_IN 10/1/2016   10:28:08 AM
847515838   Granted ORSB_GND_GYM_OUT 10/1/2016  10:57:41 AM
847522522   Granted ORSB_GND_GYM_IN 10/1/2016   11:57:10 AM
```

for eg. I need to aggregate events counts per hour. from the data we can see that for hour 10 -11, the total counts occurred for Source 'ORSB_GND_GYM_IN' is 3 and for 'ORSB_GND_GYM_OUT' is 2. How can i do this in pyspark

Comment: Are all the records from same date?

Comment: No. I have only shown sample data.This data will be for each day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Udfs to convert time to range and then do group by

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
def getInterval(time):
    start = int(time.split(":")[0])
    return str(start)+"-"+str(start+1)+" "+time.split(" ")[1]

getIntervalUdf = udf(getInterval,StringType())

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("appName").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.csv("emp",sep=",",header=True)
df.show()
df = df.withColumn("Interval",getIntervalUdf("Server_Time"))
df.show()
df = df.groupby("Server_Date","Interval","Source").count()
df.show()
```

Output

```
+-----------+--------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+
|  EventID  | AccessReason |      Source      | Server_Date | Server_Time |
+-----------+--------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+
| 847495004 | Granted      | ORSB_GND_GYM_IN  | 10/1/2016   | 7:25:52 AM  |
| 847506432 | Granted      | ORSB_GND_GYM_IN  | 10/1/2016   | 8:53:38 AM  |
| 847512725 | Granted      | ORSB_GND_GYM_IN  | 10/1/2016   | 10:18:50 AM |
| 847512768 | Granted      | ORSB_GND_GYM_IN  | 10/1/2016   | 10:19:32 AM |
| 847513357 | Granted      | ORSB_GND_GYM_OUT | 10/1/2016   | 10:25:36 AM |
| 847513614 | Granted      | ORSB_GND_GYM_IN  | 10/1/2016   | 10:28:08 AM |
| 847515838 | Granted      | ORSB_GND_GYM_OUT | 10/1/2016   | 10:57:41 AM |
| 847522522 | Granted      | ORSB_GND_GYM_IN  | 10/1/2016   | 11:57:10 AM |
+-----------+--------------+------------------+-------------+-------------+

+---------+------------+----------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
|  EventID|AccessReason|          Source|Server_Date|Server_Time|Interval|
+---------+------------+----------------+-----------+-----------+--------+
|847495004|     Granted| ORSB_GND_GYM_IN|  10/1/2016| 7:25:52 AM|  7-8 AM|
|847506432|     Granted| ORSB_GND_GYM_IN|  10/1/2016| 8:53:38 AM|  8-9 AM|
|847512725|     Granted| ORSB_GND_GYM_IN|  10/1/2016|10:18:50 AM|10-11 AM|
|847512768|     Granted| ORSB_GND_GYM_IN|  10/1/2016|10:19:32 AM|10-11 AM|
|847513357|     Granted|ORSB_GND_GYM_OUT|  10/1/2016|10:25:36 AM|10-11 AM|
|847513614|     Granted| ORSB_GND_GYM_IN|  10/1/2016|10:28:08 AM|10-11 AM|
|847515838|     Granted|ORSB_GND_GYM_OUT|  10/1/2016|10:57:41 AM|10-11 AM|
|847522522|     Granted| ORSB_GND_GYM_IN|  10/1/2016|11:57:10 AM|11-12 AM|
+---------+------------+----------------+-----------+-----------+--------+

+-----------+--------+----------------+-----+
|Server_Date|Interval|          Source|count|
+-----------+--------+----------------+-----+
|  10/1/2016|10-11 AM| ORSB_GND_GYM_IN|    3|
|  10/1/2016|  8-9 AM| ORSB_GND_GYM_IN|    1|
|  10/1/2016|10-11 AM|ORSB_GND_GYM_OUT|    2|
|  10/1/2016|11-12 AM| ORSB_GND_GYM_IN|    1|
|  10/1/2016|  7-8 AM| ORSB_GND_GYM_IN|    1|
+-----------+--------+----------------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks @Himaprasoon

Comment: I am also trying to group in minutes level, say 10 minutes. Can you tell me how can we do it.I will post the answer if i am done.

Comment: Just change the the get interval method accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For generating counts for daily/Hourly and 10 minutes interval

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType


def getHrInterval(time):
    start = int(time.split(":")[0])
    return str(start)+"-"+str(start+1)+" "+time.split(" ")[1]


def getMinInterval(time):
    hr_start = int(time.split(":")[0])
    min_start = int(str(int(time.split(":")[1])/10)+'0')
    return str(hr_start)+":"+str(min_start)+"-"+str(hr_start)+":"+str(min_start+10)+" "+time.split(" ")[1]

path = '/media/sf_VM_Shared/part-00000'
df = sqlContext.read\
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
    .option("header", "true")\
    .load(path)

getHrIntervalUdf = udf(getHrInterval, StringType())
getMinIntervalUdf = udf(getMinInterval, StringType())
df = df.withColumn("HourInterval", getHrIntervalUdf("Server_Time")).withColumn("MinInterval", getMinIntervalUdf("Server_Time"))
df = df.groupby("Server_Date", "HourInterval", "MinInterval", "Source").count()
df.show()
```

Comment: Great answer, really nice. Found that `int(time.split(":")[1])/10` has a parenthesis a bit too early and should divide by 10 before converting to integer `int( time.split(":")[1] /10 )`